# How to get the last value of a column that is not blank and match it with a cell in a Google Sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, lookup

For example, the value of the cell is `David`. Column A has the names of students. Column B has the dates. I need to get the last date if I enter the name of a student.

I was trying to use the `LOOKUP` function like:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(cell=column A),column B)
```

But it did not work. Can you please give me an idea of how to get the last date?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions with the formula:

```
=INDEX(B2:B8,MATCH(2,1/(A2:A8=D5)))
```

[image]